# Get timestamps for beginning and end of last seven days

Tags: php, date, timestamp

I am trying to output this in PHP as a UNIX timestamp instead:

```
05-30-2014 0:00:00
05-30-2014 23:59:59
05-29-2014 0:00:00
05-29-2014 23:59:59
05-28-2014 0:00:00
05-28-2014 23:59:59
05-27-2014 0:00:00
05-27-2014 23:59:59
05-26-2014 0:00:00
05-26-2014 23:59:59
05-25-2014 0:00:00
05-25-2014 23:59:59
05-24-2014 0:00:00
05-24-2014 23:59:59
```

This should be dynamic, and always show the previous seven days.

So, I am trying to get the start, and end, of each of the last seven days as a timestamp.

I was able to get the dates to output, but when including times and converting to timestamps I think it is getting messed up.

**EDIT**

I have this so far, which gets me the correct starting date and times, but this needs to be converted to a timestamp.

```
$timestamp = time()- 3600 * 24;
for ($i = 0 ; $i < 7 ; $i++) {
    echo date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', $timestamp) .'<br />';
    echo date('Y-m-d 23:59:59', $timestamp) .'<br />';  
    $timestamp -= 24 * 3600;
}
```

When I try changing it to a timestamp, and then use an online converter to reverse the timestamp it's always off by 5 hours. For example, I took the timestamp for midnight of a given date, and checked it in the online converter to see if it was correct, but it was saying 5am instead of midnight.

Comment: What I need is the very first second, and the very last second, of each day.

Comment: So, the two timestamps for a given day should cover every second of that day.

Comment: What online converter? Perhaps it is wrong.

Comment: @SherwinFlight thanks for adding your current code. Check the second edit to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$date = new DateTime();
for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
    $date->modify("last day");
    $date->setTime(0,0,0);
    echo $date->getTimestamp() . "<br/>\n";
    $date->setTime(23,59,59);
    echo = $date->getTimestamp() . "<br/>\n";
}
```

**edit**

If you want to have a specific timezone anyway, then change my first line above into:

```
    $date  = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone("Europe/Amsterdam"));
```

And set your desired timezone in stead of `Europe/Amsterdam`.

**edit 2**

Your own code that you have put in your own edit isn't that bad. You just needed to add `strtotime()` to turn your date string into a timestamp:

```
$timestamp = time()- 3600 * 24;
for ($i = 0 ; $i < 7 ; $i++) {
    echo strtotime(date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', $timestamp)) .'<br />';
    echo strtotime(date('Y-m-d 23:59:59', $timestamp)) .'<br />';  
    $timestamp -= 24 * 3600;
}
```

And don't be scared of what an online converter says. The online converter could be in a different timezone.

Comment: @SherwinFlight you're welcome. I revised my code a bit to no longer use multiple DateTime objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
$start_timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d"), date("y"));

$end_timestamp = $start_timestamp+86399;

//run it 7 times
for ($x=0; $x<7; $x++) {
    $start_timestamp = (int) $start_timestamp - 86400;
    $end_timestamp = $start_timestamp+86399;

    echo $end_timestamp."<br />".$start_timestamp."<br />";
}
```